# PHP get string from CSV for a duplicate entry

Tags: php, csv, get

I have this big file containing SWIFT numbers and bank names. I'm using the following php function for reading and comparing data:

```
function csv_query($blz) {
$cdata = -1;
$fp = fopen(DIR_WS_INCLUDES . 'data/swift.csv', 'r');
while ($data = fgetcsv($fp, 1024, ",")) {
  if ($data[0] == $blz){
    $cdata = array ('blz' => $data[0],
                    'bankname' => $data[7]);
                   // 'prz' => $data[2]
  }
}
return $cdata;
}
```

The csv files looks like that:

```
"20730054",1,"UniCredit Bank - HypoVereinsbank (ex VereinWest)","21423","Winsen (Luhe)","UniCredit Bk ex VereinWest",,"HYVEDEMM324","68","013765","M",1,"20030000"
"20750000",1,"Sparkasse Harburg-Buxtehude","21045","Hamburg","Spk Harburg-Buxtehude","52002","NOLADE21HAM","00","011993","U",0,"00000000"
"20750000",2,"Sparkasse Harburg-Buxtehude","21605","Buxtehude","Spk Harburg-Buxtehude","52002",,"00","011242","U",0,"00000000"
```

As you can see from the code, I need the first and the eight string. If the first string has no duplicates everything is ok, but if it has, most likely the eighth field of the duplicate will be empty and I get no result back. So I want to ask how to display that eighth field of the first result if the line has a duplicate.

Comment: Clean up you csv file. If it contains duplicate or incomplete information, how do you know the the first row contains the correct information. In your case you could add the return inside the if-block to get back the first result.

Comment: Clean the csv file? It is 20k lines long and is updated regularly. I know the first result contains the right  data

Comment: Then add a return $cdata; into the if-block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this will solve your problem :

```
function csv_query($blz) {
    $cdata = -1;
    $fp = fopen(DIR_WS_INCLUDES . 'data/swift.csv', 'r');
    $counter = 0; // add this line
    while ($data = fgetcsv($fp, 1024, ",")) {
        if ($data[0] == $blz && !$counter) {  //change this line
            $cdata = array(
                'blz' => $data[0],
                'bankname' => $data[7]
            );
            $counter++;  //add this line
        }
    }
    return $cdata;
}
```

Comment: This works as well, thanks! Wonder what's the difference between your solution and just putting retunr $cdata in the if statement.

Comment: With the counter you still have the read the whole file. Return will stop reading the file after the first matching row.

Comment: @Seb I agree, your solution is better than mine. feel free to edit my answer, or post a new answer.